# How to assign a different label for every bar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a grouped bar graph. The code snippet for the same is:

```
female_races_math = [x for x in data[fem_condition].groupby('race/ethnicity')['math score'].mean().sort_values()]
male_races_math = [x for x in data[mal_condition].groupby('race/ethnicity')['math score'].mean().sort_values()] 
races = ['Group A','Group B','Group C','Group D','Group E']

plt.bar(r1, female_races_math, color=['#cd20ff','#ff20c2','#ff2053','#20ff5d','#5d20ff'], label=races, width=bar_width) 
plt.bar(r2, male_races_math, color=['#cd20ff','#ff20c2','#ff2053','#20ff5d','#5d20ff'], width=bar_width)

plt.xticks([0.2,0.9], labels=['Female','Male'])
plt.title('Math Scores')
```

However, this doesn't give the desired result. I'd like each of those colors to be one of the labels. Currently, the output is

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create the intended bar plot. The colors are assigned via a dictionary to respect the order of the sorted dataframe. The legend can be created from patches using the original unsorted order.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 200
races = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D', 'Group E']
data = pd.DataFrame({'race': np.random.choice(races, N),
                     'gender': np.random.choice(['F', 'M'], N),
                     'score': np.random.randint(0, 21, N)})

female_races_math = data[data['gender'] == 'F'].groupby(['race'])['score'].mean().sort_values()
male_races_math = data[data['gender'] == 'M'].groupby(['race'])['score'].mean().sort_values()

colors = ['#cd20ff', '#ff20c2', '#ff2053', '#20ff5d', '#5d20ff']
colors_dict = {race: col for race, col in zip(races, colors)}

plt.bar(np.linspace(0.7, 1.3, 5), female_races_math, color=[colors_dict[r] for r in female_races_math.index],
        width=0.6 / 5)
plt.bar(np.linspace(1.7, 2.3, 5), male_races_math, color=[colors_dict[r] for r in male_races_math.index], width=0.6 / 5)

plt.xticks([1, 2], labels=['Female', 'Male'])
plt.title('Math Scores')

legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=col, label=race) for race, col in zip(races, colors)]

plt.legend(handles=legend_elements, title='Groups', bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1), loc="upper left")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 0):

More convenient for the viewer is to label the bars directly, rather than using a legend. If the labels are not very short, it can be a good idea to switch the x and y axes for this purpose. By the way, the seaborn library is very good at handling additional groupings, like sex in this case. So here is an alternative way to do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

female_races_math = [58, 61, 62, 65, 70]
male_races_math = [63, 65, 67, 69, 77] 
races = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D', 'Group E']

df = pd.DataFrame({'female': female_races_math, 'male': male_races_math, 
                   'race': races})
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['race'], var_name='sex', value_name='score')

sns.barplot('score', 'race', hue='sex', data=df)
plt.xlim(0, 85)
plt.title('Math Scores')
```

[image: sample plot]